# How to pass ec2 instances details to sqlite db using ruby?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

db = SQLite3::Database.new('awsec2.db')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter=> "sqlite3",
  :database=> "awsec2")

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :instances do |t|
   t.column :instance_id, :string
   t.column :status, :string
  end
end


ACCESS_KEY_ID = '.......................'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '....................'

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(:access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID, :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

ec2.instances.inject({}) { |m, i| m[i.id] = i.status; m } # How to pass those items to the instances table
```

How to store the data collected by ec2.instances methode to the database table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [metadata query tool](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) made by amazon. It is just a helper script to fetch data from [metadata url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html).